# Database doesn't receive information

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm coding an asp.net/c# web form that updates information in a SQL Server database. The problem I'm having is with the signup page. For some reason, the data will not be sent to the server. I also have very similar code for the main page, which runs fine.

Here's the signup page that does not send information to SQL Server:

```
    using System;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Configuration;

    namespace WebApplication3
    {
public partial class Signup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users(UserID, Password, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Email) VALUES (@UserID, @Password, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @Email)", conn);
      cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", TextBox1.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox3.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", TextBox4.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox5.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox6.Text);

      conn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users where UserID= '" + TextBox1.Text + "'", conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        Label1.Text="UserName is Taken";
        this.Label1.ForeColor=Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text="UserName is not Taken";
        this.Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    }
}
```

Here's the code for the main page, which runs as it should:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;

    namespace WebApplication3
    {
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Observations(UserID, DateTime, Loc_Lat, Loc_Lon, Observation, Comments) VALUES (@UserID, @DateTime, @Loc_Lat, @Loc_Lon, @Observation, @Comments)", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Observation", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loc_Lat", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loc_Lon", TextBox5.Text);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("Webform1.aspx");
    }
}
```

What is the cause of my problem?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Heres my Connection string:

```
    (<)add name="testConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=MALAYSIA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: Have you double checked you parameters or if a value is required or not required for a specific database field? You should be able to trace through (debug) and find the root cause. Set a breakpoint on ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: I suggest you read up on SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: What does your **connection string** look like?

Comment: Renove the response.redirect. Assure debug is enabled and no custom error-page is in place. My guess is that after cmd.Executethe full glory of the cause is on the screen in a yellow-tint

Comment: I tried this, however no error popped up. infact, the page still switched to login after I clicked the Sign up button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution to my problem. Turns out that in the Button Properties, **PostBackurl** was set to the login.aspx page. After deleting this, the program now works.